# Excel VBA - Separating elements of a 1D array by fixed width

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Suppose I have data in range A1:A100. I would like to split each cell in the range to multiple columns, by a fixed width, eg (0-10,10-15,15-37). I could use the Text-to-Columns function in both vba and excel itself.

My question is, if i pass the range to an array first in VBA:

```
Dim my Array as Variant
myArray = Range("A1:A100").value
```

How would i apply the following logic:

```
myNewArray = Array(myArray(0,10),myArray(10,15),myArray(15,37))
```

or maybe like this:

```
for i=1 to 100
    myNewArray(i,1) = mid(myArray(i),0,10)
    myNewArray(i,2) = mid(myArray(i),10,5)    
    myNewArray(i,3) = mid(myArray(i),15,22)
next
```

which would result in a new array of 100 rows by 3 columns, but having split the initial data at the specified points, like how a Text-to-Column approach would. But these approaches don't seem to work.

I have tried searching for answer to this but can't seem to find anything

Any help would be appreciated,
thanks

Comment: the second approach will work if you refer to `myArray` correctly.  that array even though it is referring to a single column is a 2D array.  So use `myArray(i,1)`

Comment: also Mid starts at `1` not `0` and there are only `9` in the first unless you want the 10 character used twice.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for the suggestion, edited as suggested, seems to give an error still, invalid procedure call, not sure what would be causing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Scott 's correct hint in comment you could use *one* datafield array only (based on three columns) and do a reverse loop splitting the first "column":

```
Option Explicit

Sub Split_them()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet") ' << change to your sheet name
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim v
Dim a(): a = Array(0, 11, 16, 38)   ' Fixed Widths (first item zero)
v = ws.Range("A1:C100")
For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
    For j = 3 To 1 Step -1
        v(i, j) = Mid(v(i, 1), a(j - 1) + 1, a(j) - a(j - 1))
    Next j
Next i
' write back to sheet
ws.Range("A1:C100").Offset(0, 2) = v
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly, very concise code...will adapt it to my data, thanks again